# How to describe multiple tags in one line in jade template?

Tags: html, css, pug, jade4j

I like to use jade template in express project.
And sometimes I face with these problems.
For example,

```
li: b PHONE
li +7 (914) 3164890
```

Can I put these codes in one line?
Is it possible in jade template?
If not possible, which html preprocessor do I have to use for this type of work?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Why do you want to put two `li` tags on the same line?

Comment: In any case, you can also always revert to standard HTML syntax in your Pug files (so `<li>...</li><li>...</li>`) - Pug accepts both HTML and Pug syntax

Comment: thanks. I think that would be the solution.

Comment: Glad to hear, @Mikhail! In that case, I've posted my solution as an answer, for others who might encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

For these kind of problems, you always have the option of falling back on standard HTML syntax. Pug accepts both HTML and Pug syntax in its template files, so `<li>...</li><li>...</li>` should be valid Pug code, as well.

Comment: so it is impossible on jade and it is possible on pug?

Comment: Well, Jade and Pug are one and the same thing: Pug used to be called Jade. Thus, it should be possible in both

Comment: Yeah, I thought jade and pug are the same but in fact, I can't use <li> in jade. So I can't use original html tag in jade.

Comment: Ah ok. Have you tried [tag interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#tag-interpolation)? Not sure whether it works for you, but might be worth looking at